# Bounding an $L$-smooth function $f$: $(x-y)^T \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(z) \right] \geq ? $

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a convex function with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient.

One can upper bound $( x - y)^T \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(z)\right]$ by applying Young's inequality followed by Lipschitz continuous gradient condition, that is,
\begin{align}
( x - y)^T \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(z)\right] 
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \left( \left\| x - y \right\|^2  + \underbrace{\left\| \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(z) \right\|^2}_{ \leq L^2 \left\| x - z \right\|^2 } \right) \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2} \left( \left\| x - y \right\|^2  + L^2 \left\| x - z \right\|^2 \right).
\end{align}

> How to lower bound the inequality in terms of sum and/or difference of norms between the differences among $x,y,z$ vectors:

- $ ( x - y)^T \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(z)\right] \geq \ {\color{red} ?} , \quad \forall x,y,z$.

I would highly appreciate your help.

---

p.s.: Lipschitz continuous gradient conditions are summarized here https://xingyuzhou.org/blog/notes/Lipschitz-gradient.

---

EDIT:

Does the below bound not make sense considering Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?
$ ( x - y)^T \left[ \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(z)\right] \geq \ { \color{green}{ -\frac{1}{2}\left( \left\| x - y \right\|^2 + L^2\left\| x - z \right\|^2  \right) }} , \quad \forall x,y,z$

Comment: I do not think that one can improve the lower bound if $z\ne x$

Comment: @daw Thank you for your comment. Understand.

Comment: What terms do you want to achieve on the right-hand side? Something related to cocoercivity of $\nabla f$?

Comment: @gerw Thank you for your question. Related to cocoercivity will have bound in terms of difference of gradients, but I want only in terms of norms of $x,y,z$ vectors. I hope you agree with my attempted lower bound in green color. Can we get something better than my attempted lower bound in green color?