# Upper bound: Given $L$-smooth convex $f$; $( y- x)^T \left( \nabla f(z)-\nabla f(x)\right)\leq(L/2) ( \| x-z\|^2+\| x-y\|^2+\| z-y\|^2)$?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, smooth-functions

Given $L$-smooth convex $f$, I would highly appreciate if you can confirm whether the following bound is correct or not.

\begin{align}
\left( y- x\right)^T \left( \nabla f(z)-\nabla f(x)\right) 
\leq \frac{L}{2}  \left( \| x-z\|^2+\| x-y\|^2+\| z-y\|^2 \right) \tag{$\clubsuit$}.
\end{align}

---

**Attempt**:

Since function $f$ is both $L$-smooth and convex, I particularly make use of the following two inequalities (e.g., can be found [here](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2017/optimization-inequalities-cheatsheet/) or many other books such as in Yurii Nesterov's book).

1. Three points descent lemma:
   \begin{align}
   f(x) \leq f(y) + \left( x - y \right)^T \nabla f(z) + \frac{L}{2} \| x - z \|^2 
   \end{align}
2. $$0 \leq f(y) - f(x) - \left( y - x\right)^T \nabla f(x) \leq \frac{L}{2} \| x - y \|^2 $$

To this end, we rewrite the above two respective inequalities

1.
\begin{align}
f(x) &\leq f(y) + \left( x - y \right)^T \nabla f(z) + \frac{L}{2} \| x - z \|^2 \\
\Longleftrightarrow  \left( y - x \right)^T \nabla f(z) &\leq f(y) - f(x) + \frac{L}{2} \| x - z \|^2  \tag{1}
\end{align}
2.
\begin{align}
f(y) - f(x) - \left( y - x\right)^T \nabla f(x) &\leq \frac{L}{2} \| x - y \|^2 \\
\Longleftrightarrow \left( y - x\right)^T \nabla f(x) &\geq f(y) - f(x) - \frac{L}{2} \| x - y \|^2 \tag{2} 
\end{align}

Now,
\begin{align}
\left( y- x\right)^T \left( \nabla f(z)-\nabla f(x)\right) 
=& \underbrace{\left( y- x\right)^T \nabla f(z)}_{ \text{upper bound using} \ (1) } - \underbrace{\left( y- x\right)^T  \nabla f(x)}_{ \text{lower bound using} \ (2) } \\
=& \underbrace{\left( y- x\right)^T \nabla f(z)}_{ \leq f(y) - f(x) + \frac{L}{2} \| x - z \|^2 }   
- \underbrace{\left( y- x\right)^T  \nabla f(x) }_{ \geq f(y) - f(x) - \frac{L}{2} \| x - y \|^2 } \\
\leq & f(y) - f(x) + \frac{L}{2} \| x - z \|^2 - \left[ f(y) - f(x) - \frac{L}{2} \| x - y \|^2 \right] \\
=& \frac{L}{2} \left(  \| x - z \|^2  + \| x - y \|^2  \right) \\
\leq& \frac{L}{2} \left(  \| x - z \|^2  + \| x - y \|^2 + \underbrace{\| z - y \|^2}_{\geq 0} \right)
\end{align}

This completes the proof of $(\clubsuit)$.

Comment: If $\nabla f$ is Lipschitz, then one can use Cauchy-Schwarz directly, and the term $\|x-y\|^2$ on the right-hand side is not necessary. Do I miss something?

Comment: @daw Yes, that's one possibility. I have attempted the upper bound using Caucy-Schwarz-Young inequality here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328488/bounding-an-l-smooth-function-f-x-yt-left-nabla-fx-nabla-fz : 

$( y - x)^T \left[ \nabla f(z) - \nabla f(x)\right] \leq \frac{1}{2} \left( \left\| x - y \right\|^2  + L^2 \left\| x - z \right\|^2 \right)$

Comment: @daw However, I want a bound with a factor "$L$" to $\|x-y\|^2$ and $\|z-y\|$. I think my attempted bound in this question is not tight!? 
Can we find a tighter bound that at least gives equal weight to $\|x-y\|^2$ and $\|z-y\|$ with a linear constant $L$ (not squared)?

Comment: @daw Additionally, I am sorry and do not understand how we can remove $\| x -y \|^2$ term from $(2)$. Do you have some other inequality in your mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this simple estimate:
$$
\left( y- x\right)^T \left( \nabla f(z)-\nabla f(x)\right) 
\le \|y-x\| \cdot \|\nabla f(z)-\nabla f(x)\| 
\le L \|y-x\| \cdot \|z-x\|
\le \frac L2(\|y-x\|^2 + \|z-x\|^2)
$$
??

Comment: Thank you so much. This is indeed simpler (mine is an overkill proof). I also need $\| z-y\|^2$ on the right hand side though (for my purpose). I can artificially introduce it to the right hand side since clearly norm is non-negative.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. If $a \le b \le c$ then $a \le c$. So your result follows from the above computation...

Comment: @dohmatob I guess your comment is for me. Yes, I agree with you and daw's answer -- thank you to both of you. You can ignore my "extra" need that I have commented.